# Picking TVS and ferrite beads for MCP9600 thermocouple converter

Tags: tvs, thermocouple, ferrite-bead, transient-suppression

I'm about to use the MCP9600 thermocouple voltage to I2C converter for the first time. Because I need my output to be as precise as possible, I decided to apply the recommended circuit shown in figure 6-11 [MCP9600 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP960X-L0X-RL0X-Data-Sheet-20005426F.pdf).
My problem is that I've never had to use either ferrite beads or TVS diodes in my amateur projects, so I don't really know how to pick proper parts. My guess is that ferrite beads should have a high impedance at 100 MHz in order to attenuate high-frequency noises (as I expect my useful signal to be slowly changing). When it comes to TVS, my only clue is that I should look at breakdown voltage and pick it just above \$V_{dd} R_b / (R_b + R_a)\$, \$V_{dd} R_a / (R_b + R_a)\$ in the upper pair, but I don't know how to proceed with the bottom pair. I'll be grateful for each piece of advice.

[image: Recommended circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two very common types of TVS: zener and clamp diode.

This shows a clamp diode configuration: if the input pushes below GND, the GND-side diode conducts.  If the input pushes above VDD, the VDD-side diode conducts.  Thus, as long as GND and VDD are low impedances (place a bypass capacitor near these diodes, and use a GND plane under the circuit), the ADC will be protected.

Any diode will do: 1N4148(W), BAS16, etc.  They're also available as arrays, e.g. BAT54XY, BAV99(S), NUP4301, etc.  Some even come with a clamping (zener type) integrated, e.g. CDSOT236-0504C.

(Mind that BAT54 is the odd one out in this list, a schottky diode pair.  Schottky have lower voltage drop at signal currents, but generally aren't recommended for surge application.  BAT54 seems fine with ESD, at least.  They also have higher leakage current, which can be discouraged for analog input applications.  In this case, you have a low impedance source, so the differential voltage will be fine.  The leakage may be relatively large in comparison to the megohm bias resistors shown here, though.)

The bias resistors then should set it to about mid-level, so that both diodes conduct at about the same point, when enough noise is received.  Give or take whatever the ADC/sensor says this voltage needs to be, if anything (input common mode range must be satisfied).

There should probably be capacitors there too, i.e. in parallel with the GND-side diodes.  These can be fairly large like 10-100nF.  These help the ferrite beads in filtering, even down to fairly low frequencies (~MHz).  And yes, ferrite beads have an inductive-resistive characteristic, so they are helpful for damping or filtering at high frequencies, while passing DC and low frequencies.  The low impedance (at high frequency) of these capacitors multiplies the effect.  Ferrite beads/chips of say 300Ω or thereabouts will be fine.

If you don't have VDD available in the area, or it's an inappropriate voltage, or shouldn't load the input when unpowered (not relevant to a thermocouple, but consider a logic-level say 0-5V input: if the circuit is unpowered, it will draw power from a logic-high input!), a zener type TVS may be desirable.  In this case, choose the rating based on nominal maximum input voltage: for example, a 0-5V logic input should have a unidirectional 5V TVS (which will start to conduct around 7V and  drop a peak voltage of maybe 12-20V under surge conditions -- these are typical numbers, consult datasheets for particulars).  If the input can go negative, choose bidirectional (e.g. RS-232 serial).

Comment: Thank you so much for this delightfully comprehensive answer!

Comment: How about these explicitly specialised TVS diodes, available in electronics catalogues? Could you elaborate a bit on in what cases they should be used instead of traditional diodes?
I specifically mean this category: [link](https://www2.mouser.com/c/circuit-protection/esd-suppressors-tvs-diodes/?product%20type=TVS%20Diodes)

Comment: @drydre What's left is basically bigger ones, for supply inrush, surge, etc.